# Way to Render a Webpage Sideways (90 degrees, etc)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, rendering, webkit-transform

Is there a way that I can render any webpage to load with an angle offset?

While I know you can do a [web-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotate) like: `javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);");` which works for many sites, yet I'm after an all inclusive solution.

Example issues for clarity:

1.) [Netflix.com](http://netflix.com)'s player cannot be rotated

2.) [Twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv)'s player stays intact, yet the player's dimensions are distorted causing an exaggeration of widescreen

3.) Both [Youtube](http://youtube.com) and [Google](http://Google.com)'s  pages have immense white space on the top and bottom after being rotated.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a way to circumvent having to do webkit animation and simply *load* (forgive me for a better word) a webpage turned sideways.

Thanks!

Comment: The all inclusive solution you are looking for likely does not exist, the reason those sites aren't rendering correctly is most likely due to the styling that is probably responsive to the width and height of the window throwing of the aspect ration when you rotate it. Why are you attempting this? Can you not rotate the display settings?

Comment: If you just want to do this for your own reasons, you might try [rotating the screen itself](http://superuser.com/questions/495631/how-do-i-rotate-windows-8-screen).

Comment: I've rotated my entire screen in the past, but this would be most practical for a chrome extension and it would be neat if anyone had an idea/solution. The only options I've seen out there either literally just run the script I posted, or are very limited (like 10 different domains) that they're able to cleanly turn.